# Sequential compactness in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, compactness

> *Well known result:*
>   Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and let $K$ be a
>   compact set.
>   Then, $f(K)$ is compact.

I can prove this using the definition of compactness (finding a finite subcover), but I was trying to see if it would work using sequential compactness since the two are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}$. If it does work, the proof would go something like this:

Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence in $f(K)$. Then $\{x_n\}$ defined by $x_n:= f^{-1}(y_n)$ is a sequence in $K$.

Since $K$ is compact, it is sequentially compact. So, there's a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\} = \{f^{-1}(y_{n_j})\}$ with $f^{-1}(y_{n_j}) \to x \in K$ as $j \to \infty$.

Since $f$ is continuous, we have that $f(x_{n_j})=y_{n_j} \to f(x) \in f(K)$.

---

I feel like there might be a problem here because we don't know $f$ is one-to-one. What do you think?

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is invertible?  Otherwise your definition of $\{x_n\}$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Since for each $n$, $y_n \in f(K)$, then you know that $y_n = f(x_n)$ for some $x_n \in K$.  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Hayden - Yeah, that actually just occurred to me as I was re-reading my post. Thanks!

Comment: @Hayden I believe it is an abuse of notation. Consider $f^{-1}$ not an inverse function but an inverse image: you're considering the sequence $$ \{ x_n: n \in\Bbb N \} = f^{-1} \left( \{ y_n \in K : n \in \Bbb N \} \right)$$

Comment: @MarkFantini I was considering it a pre-image; noting is to say that $f^{-1}(y_n)$ is non-empty, nor will it in general be an element of $K$.  Additionally, There is no reason that the pre-image of a countable set be countable: take for example a constant function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$.  Then $f^{-1}[\{y_n\in f[K] \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}]$ is all of $[0,1]$ for any sequence $\{y_n\}$ containing 0.

Comment: @Hayden I understand your point now. Pedrosuave has defined $x_n$ as $x_n = f^{-1}(y_n)$ which depends on the invertibility of $f$. I agree with your comment.

Comment: Maybe I should have used the notation $f^{-1}\{y_n\}$ to make it more clear that it is a pre-image, rather than an inverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to write ; for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, ($y_n\in f(K)$) there exists $x_n\in K$ such that $y_n=f(x_n)$, to avoid $f^{-1}$...

Answer (score 1):

Let $ y_n = f(x_n)$ be a sequence in $f(K)$. Then we have a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k} = x \in K.$$ But this means that $(y_n)$ has a subsequence $y_{n_k} = f(x_{n_k})$ such that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} y_{n_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = f \left( \lim_{k\to \infty} x_{n_k} \right) = f(x) = y \in f(K).$$ Since we took an arbitrary sequence in $f(K)$ and showed it has a subsequence that converges in $f(K)$ we have proved that $f(K)$ is compact.

Comment: I think you need to give additional reasoning to show that every sequence in $f[K]$ is of the form $y_n=f(x_n)$.

Comment: @Hayden Why is that? Every $y$ in $f(K)$ is image of a $x$ in $K$. Therefore any $y_n$ in $f(K)$ is image of a $x_n$ in $K$.

Comment: Yes, but there is a "choice" of such $x_n$ that needs to be made, which I'd argue is a non-trivial fact.

Comment: @Hayden Hm, I see your point. I'm interested in hearing why it is non-trivial. Can you expand on it?

Comment: Because it requires countable choice (unless I'm mistaken)

Comment: @Hayden I don't think it depends on countable choice. Whether there is only one $x_n$ or not is irrelevant. Each may lead to a different sequence but it does not matter, because since $K$ is compact, it will have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: To guarantee the existence of such a sequence at all, countable choice would be necessary.

Comment: @Hayden And why is that?

Comment: Because such a sequence is an element of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty{f^{-1}(y_n)}$.  The non-emptiness of this cartesian product (when each $f^{-1}(y_n)$ is non-empty, but that is the case here) is the contents of countable choice.  The full Axiom of Choice deals with all arbitrary products.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct proof.  It relies on the fact that $f(f^{-1}(y_{n_j}))=y_{n_j}$ which is true as $f$ is a function.  Being one-to-one would guarantees that $f^{-1}(f(y))=y$ but that's not needed here.

Comment: $f(f^{-1}(y_{n_j})) = y_{n_j}$ is guaranteed because $f: K \to f(K)$ is surjective. Otherwise you have $f(f^{-1}(A)) \subset A$ for every set $A$.

Comment: Agreed, though $y_{n_j}$ was assumed to be in $f(K)$ so we're in no danger of the set $f^{-1}(y_{n_j})$ being empty.  It's just a matter of choosing one point in the set.

Comment: Agreed, but your argument in the answer for $f(f^{-1}(y_{n_j})) = y_{n_j}$ is that it's true as "$f$ is a function". That's incorrect. It's true because of the surjectivity. Nitpicking, I know.